# Indexing and dropping DataFrame colums

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am having trouble understanding why on the first line we need to add `row`. For example : `row['G1']`.

However in the second line when we are dropping them, we don't use `row['G1']`, and we just put `['G1']`.

Also what does `r['pass'] =` do? Why do we need the `['pass']` after `r`?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

r = pd.read_csv("Data.csv", sep = ';')
len(r)
r['pass'] = r.apply(lambda row: 1 if (row['G1'] + row['G2'] + row['G3']) >= 35 else 0, axis=1)
r = r.drop(['G1', 'G2', 'G3'], axis=1)
r.head()
```

Comment: You would certainly find your answer by carefully reading the [documentation on indexing DataFrames elements](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is that `r` is a dataframe and the columns in a dataframe can be accessed by doing `df[column_name]`. So, `r['pass']` means that you are adding a new column named `pass` in your dataframe `r` in which the values will be added according to the condition in the `apply` statement.

While using [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), when you see the documentation, the input can either be a single-label or a list. Since, multiple columns are being dropped, it is simple to make a list of the columns you want to drop and pass it in the drop syntax.

> in the second line when we are dropping them, we don't use row['G1'],
>   and we just put ['G1']

If you look at the [DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) documentation, you see that it uses `DataFrame` at the beginning followed by `.drop()`. So, in this case, it is: `r.drop()`. When you do `r.drop(['G1', 'G2', 'G3'], axis=1)`, what you are doing is selecting the columns list you want to drop (in this case `['G1', 'G2', 'G3']`). And `axis=1` means that you want to drop the values from the columns.

Have a look at the documentation for more information.